# Why fscanf fails during multithreaded read?

Tags: c, multithreading, gdb, valgrind

I’m new to pthreads. I am running a thread that does binary search for a set of random keys in a sorted file, and read the key's value back:

```
int binary_search_in_disk(int k_level, int key){

  if (!file_exist(level_fname)){
    return -1;
  }

  char *line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;

  int num, file_charsize, low_key, mid_key, high_key, value, op;

  // file position measured in long int bytes (4), point to the first char of the 
  // line
  int low, mid, high;

  FILE* level_file = fopen(level_fname, "r");
  printf("fname: %s ,", level_fname);

  // find low key 
  low = 0;
  printf("file exists? %d ,", file_exist(level_fname)); // return 1, file exists

  num = fscanf(level_file, "%d%d%d\n", &low_key, &value, &op); // seg fault, file does not exist
 ... 
}
```

I have another thread that reads key value pairs from the same file, then destroy the file and rename another file in its place. I added `printf` in the function that does read and destroy, and the printf shows that the seg fault happens when both threads are reading. GDB also shows that at the time of the seg fault, both threads are reading from the file. When I ran the program, the seg fault occurs at different values of read. What is causing the `level_file` to suddenly become NULL?

GDB:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb73ffb40 (LWP 13213)]
__isoc99_fscanf (stream=0x0, format=0x804b641 "%d%d%d\n") at isoc99_fscanf.c:30
30  isoc99_fscanf.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __isoc99_fscanf (stream=0x0, format=0x804b641 "%d%d%d\n") at isoc99_fscanf.c:30
#1  0x0804ae60 in binary_search_in_disk (k_level=1, key=89) at lib.c:894
#2  0x0804ac04 in search (k_level=1, key=89) at lib.c:809
#3  0x080490da in get (key=89) at lsm.c:56
#4  0x08048dc9 in run_get (args=0x804e0c8) at concurrent_main.c:181
#5  0xb7f71f70 in start_thread (arg=0xb73ffb40) at pthread_create.c:312
#6  0xb7ea7bee in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:129
(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 3 (Thread 0xb73ffb40 (LWP 13213)):
#0  __isoc99_fscanf (stream=0x0, format=0x804b641 "%d%d%d\n") at isoc99_fscanf.c:30
#1  0x0804ae60 in binary_search_in_disk (k_level=1, key=89) at lib.c:894
#2  0x0804ac04 in search (k_level=1, key=89) at lib.c:809
#3  0x080490da in get (key=89) at lsm.c:56
#4  0x08048dc9 in run_get (args=0x804e0c8) at concurrent_main.c:181
#5  0xb7f71f70 in start_thread (arg=0xb73ffb40) at pthread_create.c:312
#6  0xb7ea7bee in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:129

Thread 2 (Thread 0xb7dbab40 (LWP 13212)):
#0  0xb7fdd428 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7eb5151 in __lll_unlock_wake_private ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/i686/../i486/lowlevellock.S:349
#2  0xb7e21809 in _L_unlock_156 () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0xb7e21768 in _IO_acquire_lock_fct (p=<synthetic pointer>) at libioP.h:905
#4  _IO_puts (str=0x804b738 "Read from disk ... ") at ioputs.c:37
#5  0x0804a39e in merge_in_memory_disk () at lib.c:556
#6  0x080497c7 in lsm_merge (k_level=0) at lib.c:162
#7  0x08049097 in put (key=256, value=256, op=0) at lsm.c:26
#8  0x08048cfa in run_put (args=0x804e028) at concurrent_main.c:128
#9  0xb7f71f70 in start_thread (arg=0xb7dbab40) at pthread_create.c:312
#10 0xb7ea7bee in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:129

Thread 1 (Thread 0xb7dbb700 (LWP 13208)):
#0  0xb7fdd428 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7f73178 in pthread_join (threadid=3084626752, thread_return=0x0) at pthread_join.c:92
#2  0x08049029 in main (argc=6, argv=0xbfffefd4) at concurrent_main.c:270
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 3    Thread 0xb73ffb40 (LWP 13213) "concurrent_main" __isoc99_fscanf (stream=0x0, 
    format=0x804b641 "%d%d%d\n") at isoc99_fscanf.c:30
  2    Thread 0xb7dbab40 (LWP 13212) "concurrent_main" 0xb7fdd428 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
  1    Thread 0xb7dbb700 (LWP 13208) "concurrent_main" 0xb7fdd428 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
```

Valgrind:

```
==13748== Thread 3:
==13748== Invalid read of size 4
==13748==    at 0x40FE195: __isoc99_fscanf (isoc99_fscanf.c:30)
==13748==    by 0x804AE69: binary_search_in_disk (lib.c:892)
==13748==    by 0x804AC0D: search (lib.c:809)
==13748==    by 0x80490E3: get (lsm.c:56)
==13748==    by 0x8048DCD: run_get (concurrent_main.c:183)
==13748==    by 0x4092F6F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==13748==    by 0x4193BED: clone (clone.S:129)
==13748==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==13748== 
==13748== 
==13748== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==13748==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==13748==    at 0x40FE195: __isoc99_fscanf (isoc99_fscanf.c:30)
==13748==    by 0x804AE69: binary_search_in_disk (lib.c:892)
==13748==    by 0x804AC0D: search (lib.c:809)
==13748==    by 0x80490E3: get (lsm.c:56)
==13748==    by 0x8048DCD: run_get (concurrent_main.c:183)
==13748==    by 0x4092F6F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==13748==    by 0x4193BED: clone (clone.S:129)
==13748==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==13748==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==13748==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==13748==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==13748==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==13748== 
==13748== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13748==     in use at exit: 482,004 bytes in 2,046 blocks
==13748==   total heap usage: 2,679 allocs, 633 frees, 576,804 bytes allocated
==13748== 
==13748== LEAK SUMMARY:
==13748==    definitely lost: 122,280 bytes in 1,019 blocks
==13748==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13748==      possibly lost: 272 bytes in 2 blocks
==13748==    still reachable: 359,452 bytes in 1,025 blocks
==13748==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13748== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==13748== 
==13748== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13748== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==13748== ERROR SUMMARY: 188 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Killed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
FILE* level_file = fopen(level_fname, "r");
printf("fname: %s ,", level_fname);
printf("file exists? %d ,", file_exist(level_fname));
```

isn't a proper way to handle errors: a file may exist, but not be readable, or it may exist now but not exist when `fopen` was called, or you could be out of memory, or out of file descriptors, or ...

What you should do is this:

```
FILE *level_file = fopen(level_fname, "r");
if (level_file == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open '%s' for reading: %s\n", level_fname, sterror(errno));
  return -1;
}
```

Had you done that, the error would have been obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue: `Too many open files`